# Create new outlook email using Windows Forms

Tags: c#, outlook

This is probably very beginner question. I am trying to create my first Windows Forms application and would like to create an outlook email message by clicking a button on my form.

The problem is that there are 13 errors mainly saying:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Outlook' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Offer
>   machine v.0.0.1   C:\Users\PC\source\repos\Offer machine v.0.0.1\Offer
>   machine v.0.0.1\Form1.cs  29  Active

I have added references to my project:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Offer_machine_v._0._0._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> lstAllRecipients = new List<string>();
                //Below is hardcoded - can be replaced with db data
                lstAllRecipients.Add("sanjeev.kumar@testmail.com");
                lstAllRecipients.Add("chandan.kumarpanda@testmail.com");

                Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                Outlook.Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector;
                // Thread.Sleep(10000);

                // Recipient
                Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMailItem.Recipients;
                foreach (String recipient in lstAllRecipients)
                {
                    Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(recipient);
                    oRecip.Resolve();
                }

                //Add CC
                Outlook.Recipient oCCRecip = oRecips.Add("THIYAGARAJAN.DURAIRAJAN@testmail.com");
                oCCRecip.Type = (int)Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC;
                oCCRecip.Resolve();

                //Add Subject
                oMailItem.Subject = "Test Mail";

                // body, bcc etc...

                //Display the mailbox
                oMailItem.Display(true);
            }
            catch (Exception objEx)
            {
                Response.Write(objEx.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void Label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have added Outlook interops to the project References twice.

[image: Outlook automation references]

As for the error message, you just need to add an alias to the Outlook namespace:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
```

Also, you may find the [C# app automates Outlook (CSAutomateOutlook)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9) sample project helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding the proper using to your code. You need to add:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

Without this line you should type the full namespace before each object from the Interop libraries. With that using in place you can remove all the `Outlook.` before the objects coming from the interop. But the one creating the main Application object needs the full namespace to avoid conflicts with the Application class defined in Winforms.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = 
                   new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
_MailItem oMailItem = (_MailItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
Inspector oInspector = oMailItem.GetInspector;

..... and so on ....
```